# How do I unimport a function in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to remove symbols that are imported so that they are unavailable as methods in the object, but `no` does not seem to work, maybe I don't understand no, or there's another way.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

# still has carp after no carp
package Test0 {
    use Carp qw( carp );
    sub new {
        my $class = shift;
        my $self  = {};

        carp 'good';

        bless $self, $class;
        return $self;
    }
    no Carp;
}

my $t0 = Test0->new;

ok( ! $t0->can('carp'), 'can not carp');

# below passes correctly
package Test1 {
    use Carp qw( carp );
    use namespace::autoclean;

    sub new {
        my $class = shift;
        my $self  = {};

        carp 'good';

        bless $self, $class;
        return $self;
    }
}
my $t1 = Test1->new;
ok( ! $t1->can('carp'), 'can not carp');
done_testing;
```

unfortunately I can't use [namespace::autoclean](https://metacpan.org/module/namespace::autoclean) because I've been restricted to modules that are only part of core perl (yeah stupid but c'est la vie).

without just rewriting `namespace::autoclean` is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you do what namespace::auto clean does this? It does what you want, but even without using it as a module you want to avoid doing what it does, as if it exists for no good reason since there must be a simpler way to get the job done.

Comment: @briandfoy it's possible that I could, but I figured there might be a simpler way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe namespace::autoclean deletes the glob:

```
delete $Test0::{carp};
```

Without hardcoding the package:

```
my $pkg = do { no strict 'refs'; \%{ __PACKAGE__."::" } };
delete $pkg->{carp};
```

If you insist on leaving strict on, you can fool strict (but it's no more or less safe):

```
my $pkg = \%::;
$pkg = $pkg->{ $_ . '::' } for split /::/, __PACKAGE__;
delete $pkg->{carp};
```

PS — Why is code from StackOverflow acceptable if code from CPAN isn't?

Comment: p.s. F* knows. I'm tired of trying to get premature optimizers with NIHS to get sane.

Comment: using a combination of this and @IlmariKaronen's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10307099/206466), makes sense to not import where I'm using once.

Answer (score 11):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but a simple workaround is not to import the functions in the first place.  This will work just fine:

```
use Carp ();  # import nothing

Carp::carp 'good';
```