# What does the keyword `no` actually do in Perl?

Tags: perl, module

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10306916/206466) has solved my problem, but left me with a lack of understanding.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

# still has carp after no Carp
package Test0 {
    use Carp qw( carp );
    sub new {
        my $class = shift;
        my $self  = {};

        carp 'good';

        bless $self, $class;
        return $self;
    }
    no Carp;
}

my $t0 = Test0->new;

ok( ! $t0->can('carp'), 'cannot carp');
```

This test does not pass, which means `no ...` doesn't do what I think it does, which includes unimporting the symbols. I've read [`perldoc no`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/no.html), but it really seems to be rather unenlightening. Given the results of this code I'd say that it doesn't exactly do what it advertises.

What does `no` do? When and why should I be using it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`no` calls a package's `unimport()`, whereas `use` calls `import()`, both silently skipping the case where no desired sub is found.

However, few packages — indeed, mostly only the pragma modules — support `unimport()`.

Comment: It could be argued that `Exporter` not defining an `unimport` to go with its `import` is a bug.

Comment: @geekosaur, I agree.  (It could be argued :))